# Manjaro KDE (Plasma 5) and Wayland - Clipboard (copy/paste) issues with Wine

Tags: xorg, kde, wine, kde-plasma-5, wayland

I use Linux Manjaro KDE (Plasma 5) and I am using the Wayland communication protocol for my display server (previously I used X11).

When making this change (Wayland to X11) I started having problems with the clipboard on my Linux Manjaro KDE when I need to use the clipboard (copy/paste) between Wine applications and the rest of the system, especially Chrome which often crashes. Other times, in this same context, the clipboard does not work correctly.

What can I do to deal with these problems with the clipboard on my Linux Manjaro KDE?

[Ref(s).: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/copy-paste-problem-works-every-other-time/36957/20?u=eduardolucioac ]

**Thanks!**